# how to create VIRTUAL column with an if Query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, virtual, create-table

how can i create a virtual cloumn with conditions
i have a table with columns `a`  `b` `c`

**c** should be virtual with conditions  =>

```
 1- if 'b' < 16.5 the value  should be "1"
 2- if 'b' BETWEEN 16.5 AND 18.5 the value should be "2"
 3- if 'b' = 25 the value should be "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case when

```
 select a, b, case when b <16.5 then 1 
                   when b between 16.5 and 18.5 then 2 
                   when b = 25 then 3  
                  end  c
  from my_table
```

You should also manage the others case with else

```
 select a, b, case when b <16.5 then 1 
                   when b between 16.5 and 18.5 then 2 
                   when b = 25 then 3  
                   else 0
                  end  c
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**

**STEP 1** - First of all create a table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    a float,
    b float,
    c float
);
```

**STEP 2** - If b < 16.5 then update value in *c* column.

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET c = 1 WHERE b < 16.5;
```

**STEP 3** - If b between 16.5 and 18.5 then update value in *c* column.

```
UPDATE table_name SET c = 2 WHERE b >= 16.5 AND b <= 18.5;
```

**OR**

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET c = 2 WHERE b BETWEEN 16.5 AND 18.5;
```

**STEP 4** - If b = 25 then update value in *c* column.

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET c = 3 WHERE b = 25;
```

Comment: is there any method how to do that  from the begining of the table's creation ? 
when creating the table in the algorithm ?

Comment: It depends on the programming language.
For ref- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Comment: Please refer blog- http://codefunlife.blogspot.com/2018/03/dropbox-salesforce-add-asset-management.html